# How can I perform a VLOOKUP by updating only the newly added data each month in a main database while preserving the previously looked-up information?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have 2 tables, the main data base with data that gets added monthly, with a name, date and corresponding rating. I also have a lookup table that has names and rating of that person, the rating of the person can change at any time, and will be reviewed monthly. So whenever data is added to my data base for a specific month, I want a vlook-up that will only apply the recently added data for that month and keep the old ratings that were previously vlooked-up. This means for the next month, we will keep the ratings we looked-up this month and our formula/lookup can apply for next month, and so on.

Comment: Can you include some example data?

Comment: Sounds like you should apply (nest) `Filter()` within your Vlookup range (table array). How to accomplish this will depend how the data in the main data base is formated and updated, which is not spelled out in your ask.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a vlookup that matches multiple fields (name *and* date). The simplest answer is to use an `IFS()`-type formula to check both columns, like:

[image: screenshot]

Adding a column for date in your lookup table can be used to include the ratings from previous months.

---

or for text results, you could add a column to your database that concatenates Name+Date, and just use vlookup normally on that column